# Categories not appearing in Top-horizantal menu

Tags: category, home

I've created a couple of categories for my products but none of the category is appearing on the homepage. It should appear as a Top-horizantal bar but I couldn't see any trace of it. Any idea about what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to incorporate any code to make it appear? I'm sorry I don't have sound knowledge of PHP. Please help.

Website: http://www.dirtrades.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the categories that you have created reside within the "Default Category" folder (assuming you have not renamed it). Also under "General Information" Is Active" must be set to Yes and "Include in Navigation Menu" must be set to Yes.